# Modify systemd unit file without altering upstream unit file

Tags: systemd

I have installed the `pimd` service by means of `apt`. This comes with an upstream `systemd` unit file (`/lib/systemd/system/pimd.service`).

I want the service to be restarted when for some reason it gets killed, hence I wish to add the line `Restart = always` in the unit file.

However, I don’t want to modify the upstream unit file.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Closely related: [How to set environment variable in systemd service?](http://serverfault.com/q/413397/126632)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set environment variable in systemd service?](https://serverfault.com/questions/413397/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-systemd-service)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You have two options:

- Copy the unit file from `/lib/systemd/system/` to `/etc/systemd/system/`.
  And then make your modifications in `/etc/systemd/system/pimd.service` to completely override the unit file(s) supplied by the package maintainer.

  The command **`systemctl edit --full <service-name>`** automates this for you.
- You can alter or add specific configuration settings for a unit, without having to modify unit files by creating `.conf` files in a drop-in directory  `/etc/systemd/system/<unit-name>.<unit-type>.d/`
  i.e. create a `/etc/systemd/system/pimd.service.d/restart.conf`

  The command **`systemctl edit <service-name>`** performs these steps for you.

See [`man systemd.unit`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)

Comment: The second option can be made easier by using `systemctl edit <service-name>`

Comment: And the first one by using `systemctl edit --full <service-name>`.

Comment: Please restructure this answer so that the ```system edit``` commands come first in each section. It is much better to use the tools to avoid typos and misconfigurations.

Comment: It is better to use `.include` instead of copying entire file.

Answer (score 30):

The RHEL documentation recommends two ways:

1. Extend the default unit file by creating a configuration directory and file under `/etc/systemd/system/[name-goes-here].service.d/config_name.conf`

In this case the file would need to contain something like this:

```
[Service]
Restart=always
```

This is what `systemctl edit [name-goes-here]` does, it creates that directory and `override.conf` within it.

2. > Create a copy of the original unit file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` in `/etc/systemd/system/` and make changes there.

I would try option one but they are both viable options. Either way remember to run `systemctl daemon-reload` after making the changes.

[RHEL documentation on Creating and Modifying systemd Unit Files](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/chap-managing_services_with_systemd#sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_File_Modify)

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a script to read the upstream configuration, modify it, and spit it out to drop-in file.

For example, I use Chef and here's a piece of ruby (library) that parses marathon systemd unit file to get original ExecStart from it

```
require 'inifile'

module Dcos
  def get_execstart_from_unit_file
    marathon_systemd_unit_file = 
    IniFile.load('/etc/systemd/system/dcos-marathon.service')
    return marathon_systemd_unit_file['Service']['ExecStart']
  end
end
```

Then in the recipe, I create the drop-in file to append an option to ExecStart

```
chef_gem 'inifile'

exec_start_orig = get_execstart_from_unit_file

systemd_service_drop_in 'dcos-marathon' do
  override 'dcos-marathon.service'
  precursor 'Service' => { 'ExecStart' => nil }
  service do
    exec_start exec_start_orig + ' --env_vars_prefix "DCOS_MARATHON_"'
  end
end
```

Comment: Excellent, I'm also trying to achieve that with Chef! Thank you.

Comment: Looks like this `systemd_service_drop_in` method is not part Chef. Are you using the https://github.com/nathwill/chef-systemd cookbook? If that's the case, please tell it in your answer.