# Redis not starting with systemctl

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, redis, systemctl

I have installed redis on an ubuntu 16.04 machine and if I run `/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/cluster/7000/redis.conf` it starts up and I can connect to it without issues.

However I want to start it using `systemctl start redis`, so I have created the following file at `/etc/systemd/system/redis7000.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Redis In-Memory Data Store
After=network.target

[Service]
User=redis
Group=redis
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/cluster/7000/redis.conf
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/redis-cli shutdown
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and the redis config has `supervised systemd` set

which I think looks good, but I get the following errors:

```
Jan 19 14:54:27 ip-172-31-42-18 systemd[1]: Started Redis In-Memory Data Store.
Jan 19 14:54:27 ip-172-31-42-18 redis-server[21661]: 21661:C 19 Jan 14:54:27.680 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
Jan 19 14:54:27 ip-172-31-42-18 redis-server[21661]: 21661:C 19 Jan 14:54:27.680 # Redis version=4.0.6, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=21661, just started
Jan 19 14:54:27 ip-172-31-42-18 redis-server[21661]: 21661:C 19 Jan 14:54:27.680 # Configuration loaded
Jan 19 14:54:27 ip-172-31-42-18 redis-server[21661]: 21661:C 19 Jan 14:54:27.680 # systemd supervision requested, but NOTIFY_SOCKET not found
Jan 19 14:54:27 ip-172-31-42-18 systemd[1]: redis7000.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 19 14:54:27 ip-172-31-42-18 systemd[1]: redis7000.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 19 14:54:27 ip-172-31-42-18 systemd[1]: redis7000.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 19 14:54:27 ip-172-31-42-18 systemd[1]: redis7000.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 19 14:54:27 ip-172-31-42-18 systemd[1]: Stopped Redis In-Memory Data Store.
```

And I am not even sure what this means, so could someone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To run redis under systemd, you need to set `supervised systemd`.

See the configuration file:

```
# If you run Redis from upstart or systemd, Redis can interact with your
# supervision tree. Options:
#   supervised no      - no supervision interaction
#   supervised upstart - signal upstart by putting Redis into SIGSTOP mode
#   supervised systemd - signal systemd by writing READY=1 to $NOTIFY_SOCKET
#   supervised auto    - detect upstart or systemd method based on
#                        UPSTART_JOB or NOTIFY_SOCKET environment variables
# Note: these supervision methods only signal "process is ready."
#       They do not enable continuous liveness pings back to your supervisor.
supervised no
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
supervised systemd
```

You can also pass this on the command line, which overrides the setting in `redis.conf`. Red Hat based systems do this. This also allows for running the same redis instance manually or from systemd without changing the config file.

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis.conf --supervised systemd
```

---

In addition, you also need to tell systemd that redis will be operating in this mode by setting `Type=notify` in the `[Service]` section.

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: At least for the new redis 7.0, this answer is no longer valid. Redis will stop and start 5 times in quick succession, then end up stopped. When the forking/pidfile older style method is used, starting Redis will hang for 90 seconds (by default), after which it will not start.

Comment: @aphid exactly, yes it is doing that! did you find a fix?

Comment: @Timmerz comment out `TimeoutStartSec=infinity`, or change`infinity` to 30 (or other value) so `TimeoutStartSec=30`

Answer (score 14):

As I cannot add a comment due to lack of reputation, please take this as a comment to Michael Hampston's answer.

When modifying the `systemd` service file, use the command `systemctl edit redis-server` to create an override.  In the resulting edit window, type the following:

```
[Service]
Type=notify
```

Save and exit then finish the installation `apt install -f`.

If you modify the service in `/lib/systemd/system`, you'll lose those edits on next update.

See: [modify systemd unit file without altering upstream unit file](https://serverfault.com/questions/840996/modify-systemd-unit-file-without-altering-upstream-unit-file)

PS:  This question saved me from having to scratch my head for too long as I just encountered the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to debug this is copy `ExecStart` line and execute on terminal you will get the error frequently. So it will give you more hints to debug and solve.

I have done the same and got exact error and got it solved.

Comment: The journal output already gives hints on what the problem may be: " NOTIFY_SOCKET not found" Do you have further info on this Redis problem?

Comment: Yes journalctl -u service-name also gives output.

Comment: `journalctl -u redis` gave info about the error in my case
`*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 147
 >>> 'supervised systemd        #signal systemd'
 Bad directive or wrong number of arguments`

which was to remove the commented out part after `systemd`

Answer (score 0):

```
# If you run Redis from upstart or systemd, Redis can interact with your
# supervision tree. Options:
#   supervised no      - no supervision interaction
#   supervised upstart - signal upstart by putting Redis into SIGSTOP mode
#                        requires "expect stop" in your upstart job config
#   supervised systemd - signal systemd by writing READY=1 to $NOTIFY_SOCKET
#                        on startup, and updating Redis status on a regular
#                        basis.
#   supervised auto    - detect upstart or systemd method based on
#                        UPSTART_JOB or NOTIFY_SOCKET environment variables
# Note: these supervision methods only signal "process is ready."
#       They do not enable continuous pings back to your supervisor.
#
# The default is "no". To run under upstart/systemd, you can simply uncomment
# the line below:
#
supervised systemd
```

under supervised systemd option you would be able to start redis as systemd. But for proper functioning of systemd for redis. For this you need to set the daemonize value to yes.

```
daemonize yes
```

Followed by proper systemd service

```
[Unit]
Description=Redis data structure server
Documentation=https://redis.io/documentation
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
    
[Service]
User=redis
Group=redis
TimeoutSec=1200
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/redis-cli shutdown
LimitNOFILE=10032
NoNewPrivileges=yes
Type=forking
TimeoutStartSec=infinity
TimeoutStopSec=infinity
UMask=0077
Restart=always
    
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

On a more modern system, this worked for me instead:

Add these 3 lines to the service file `/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service` under the `[service]` section:

```
RuntimeDirectory=redis
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/redis/redis-server.pid
```

And add this to `/etc/redis/redis.conf`

```
pidfile /var/run/redis/redis-server.pid
supervised systemd
daemonize yes
```

Answer (score 0):

On Redis 7.2, this redis.service file works for me:

```
[Unit]
Description=Redis In-Memory Data Store
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/6379.conf --supervised systemd
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/redis-cli shutdown
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: It is a partial answer and also an example. I think it can remain.