# Redis service hangs with systemctl and Type=notify

Tags: centos7, systemd, redis

I have followed this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/893075/210494. I have CentOS 7.8.

redis.service

```
[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/opt/redis/bin/redis-server /opt/redis/conf/redis-master.conf
TimeoutStartSec=60
TimeoutStopSec=60
TimeOutSec=90
RestartSec=5s
Restart=on-success
```

redis-master.conf

```
daemonize no
supervised systemd
```

When I run this service, the Redis process starts but the `systemctl` hangs and I have to press Ctrl-C to get back to shell.

This is in the logs:

```
69486:C 28 Aug 2020 17:31:14.545 # Redis version=6.0.6, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=69486, just started
69486:C 28 Aug 2020 17:31:14.545 # Configuration loaded
69486:C 28 Aug 2020 17:31:14.545 # WARNING supervised by systemd - you MUST set appropriate values for TimeoutStartSec and TimeoutStopSec in your service unit.
69486:M 28 Aug 2020 17:31:14.546 * Increased maximum number of open files to 4096 (it was originally set to 1024).
69486:M 28 Aug 2020 17:31:14.547 * Running mode=standalone, port=6380.
69486:M 28 Aug 2020 17:31:14.547 # Server initialized
```

If I comment out `Type=notify`, then systemctl finishes immediatelly but this is in the logs.

```
68629:C 28 Aug 2020 17:29:58.933 # Redis version=6.0.6, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=68629, just started
68629:C 28 Aug 2020 17:29:58.933 # Configuration loaded
68629:C 28 Aug 2020 17:29:58.933 # WARNING supervised by systemd - you MUST set appropriate values for TimeoutStartSec and TimeoutStopSec in your service unit.
68629:C 28 Aug 2020 17:29:58.933 # systemd supervision requested, but NOTIFY_SOCKET not found
68629:M 28 Aug 2020 17:29:58.933 * Increased maximum number of open files to 4096 (it was originally set to 1024).
68629:M 28 Aug 2020 17:29:58.934 * Running mode=standalone, port=6380.
68629:M 28 Aug 2020 17:29:58.934 # Server initialized
```

Where is the problem? I found DigitalOcean tutorial where they do not have `Type=notify` and I found Redis issues when they successfully recommended `Type=notify`.

**Update**

```
Job for redis.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status redis.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@DB dev]# systemctl status redis
● redis.service - Redis
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/redis.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Sun 2020-08-30 12:06:58 CEST; 46min ago
  Process: 11134 ExecStart=/opt/app/redis/default/bin/redis-server /opt/app/redis/default/conf/redis-master.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 11134 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Aug 30 12:05:57 DB systemd[1]: Starting Redis...
Aug 30 12:06:58 DB systemd[1]: redis.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
Aug 30 12:06:58 DB systemd[1]: Failed to start Redis.
Aug 30 12:06:58 DB systemd[1]: Unit redis.service entered failed state.
Aug 30 12:06:58 DB systemd[1]: redis.service failed.
```

Comment: Well, that isn't making the slightest bit of sense. Check the journal and `dmesg` to see if there's anything else unusual going on.

Comment: It would have been helpful to mention that you compiled redis yourself. Nobody would generally expect anyone to do that for a production system.

Comment: What? Redis does not provide binaries, does it? https://redis.io/download

Comment: If you used a binary then it would have been helpful to mention that too. This also is something that would be unexpected.

Comment: Though, now that I think about it more, redis official binaries _not_ compiled with systemd support, and not throwing an error when you try to use systemd, is a really bad thing. I suggest filing a bug report.

Comment: They have incorporated my PR to update the documentation. But throwing an error would be good habbit. I can report it too.

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/7735

Answer (score 11):

Ok, the problem was that `systemd` support is not compiled by default. You need to compile it explicitelly. I will write a PR to update README.md in sources because this is not explained.

This [commit](https://github.com/redis/redis/commit/129d14e1431e913426485526663e1a9aac67838c) is responsible for this behaviour. I found it in this issue: https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/7217

```
yum install systemd-devel
make BUILD_WITH_SYSTEMD=yes USE_SYSTEMD=yes
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Been debugging this for two hours!

Comment: For me it worked by installing systemd-devel as mentioned. It worked without adding the options (BUILD_WITH_SYSTEMD=yes USE_SYSTEMD=yes). redis-6.2.12