# apache2: Saves files on /tmp in a 'system-private-[hash]' instead of just saving folders as defined in the code

Tags: file-permissions, apache2

For some reason, when I try to save a file (generated by PHP under `/www/appname/module`) -  it is saved under

`/tmp/systemd-private-015eb2e9f67b4eef862c68e99fe0ba30-apache2.service-9h6i08`

and when aiming files to get saved under

`/tmp/somename`

files get saved under

`/tmp/systemd-private-015eb2e9f67b4eef862c68e99fe0ba30-apache2.service-9h6i08/tmp/somename`.

How do i disable this feature and just save files "regularly" to the /tmp directory?

What is the purpose of this default feature anyway?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is a systemd security setting that creates a service specific private temp directory.

Your apache systemd unit will file have a setting:

```
...
[Service]
ExecStart=...
PrivateTmp=yes
...
```

This option will ensure that the `/tmp` directory the service will see is private and isolated from the host system's `/tmp`. `/tmp` traditionally has been a shared space for all local services and users. Over the years it has been a major source of security problems for a multitude of services. Symlink attacks and DoS vulnerabilities due to guessable `/tmp` temporary files are common. By isolating the service's `/tmp`from the rest of the host, such vulnerabilities become moot.
 Source: http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/security.html

You can configure multiple services to share a `PrivateTmp` with `JoinsNamespaceOf=` which may be desirable to setting `PrivateTmp=no`

Comment: where can i find this settings file? I looked in `/etc/apache2` and `/etc/systemd` and I cant see something similar..

Comment: See [this Q&A](https://serverfault.com/q/840996/37681) on how to modify/customise  systemd unit files

Comment: try ``cat /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service`` for Debian

Answer (score 0):

My PrivateTmp said true, not yes. Changed it to false. Not sure if it takes other values like "no", "false", etc.

Note I needed to systemctl daemon-reload after changing the service unit then systemctl restart apache2.