# php and apache not seeing anything in there defined tmp dirs

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, systemd, 500-error

How to check logs for non application 500s?

we have standard php and apache but not seeing anything in there defined tmp dirs

I have actually 2 issues one is routing logs for https://www.test.com

other is that the '/tmp/' or our dev on system currently is writing to a private system dir

e.g. /tmp/systemd-private-840c0bc8008041628bfc86e69a7bb944-httpd.service-z3oDEZ/tmp/

our old server wrote to '/tmp/' without the 'systemd-...' additions

I also have an issue with the '/tmp' directory storing things to private directories based on service executing the request rather than the. '/tmp' root. Do anyone help me how can resolve that?

**We have CRONs that require static tmp dir
is there a way to have the tmp be created consistently**

From the answers like
serverfault.com/a/912098/984089

So i understand that  '/etc/systemd/system/[name-goes-here].service.d/config_name.conf' should not already exist, right?

that file doesn't exist on our old server and the 'tmp' issue isn't present there is there some other way this is configured/can be?

any short of help would be apricated ?

Comment: See for example: https://serverfault.com/a/912098/984089

Comment: The file doesn't exist on our old server and the 'tmp' issue isn't present there is there some other way this is configured/can be?