# Executing a command before starting a systemd service

Tags: systemd

I want to execute a script before starting a service every time the service is started.

I know that I can use `ExecStartPre` inside the service definition file, but I wonder if it's possible to achieve without editing a file which comes from the service's package.

The script is a simple command which exits when it's done, it creates files which are used by the main service (it fetches TLS certificates and keys from secure storage).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify systemd unit file without altering upstream unit file](https://serverfault.com/questions/840996/modify-systemd-unit-file-without-altering-upstream-unit-file)

Comment: @HermanB yes it looks like the second option in the accepted answer does what I need. The service change is done in batch (as part of AMI creation with Packer), so the "manual" steps make more sense in my context instead of using the interactive `systemctl edit`. But it's good to learn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. You can use specific independant includes:

```
mkdir /etc/systemd/service/<servicename>.service.d
echo /etc/systemd/service/<servicename>.service.d/<anything>.conf << EOF
[Service]
ExecStartPre=<path to script>
EOF
systemctl daemon-reload
```

et voila.

Reference: Search for "*drop-in*" in [systemd.unit — Unit configuration](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I made some corrections and improvements to the answer.