# Ubuntu/Apache: /tmp files unexpectedly removed

Tags: linux, filesystems

I'm losing files in `/tmp` on current Ubuntu (22.04.2), possibly related to virtualisation. Any insights appreciated. This is not a normal cleanup; the file is lost immediately.

I have two systems: a remote VPS, and a local staging system, both running the same software. On both systems, `/tmp` is not a `tmpfs`; it's part of the LVM volume group mounted at `/`.

Apache runs `program1` and `program2` immediately after each other:

1. `program1` creates a new subdirectory under `/tmp`, with 2 files: `file1` (a Python source file) and `file2` (the output of `file1`). If debug is enabled, `file1` is retained; otherwise, it it deleted after creating `file2` (with a C library `remove`)
2. `program2` returns `file2` to the client

This all works as expected on the staging system. If debug is enabled, the new `/tmp/xxx` directory is still on the filesystem, and contains both `file1` and `file2`. If debug isn't enabled, it contains only `file2`.

On the VPS:

1. if debug is *not* enabled, everything works, but there's nothing left under `/tmp`
2. if debug *is* enabled, `program2` fails, reporting that `file2` doesn't exist

I have 'fixed' the code by removing the C lib `remove`, so that `file1` is always retained, but I don't understand what's going on - it appears that the file remove has somewhere triggered a remove of the entire directory.

Comment: Do you have functionality in the application that removes these files after certain times? I'd suspect permissions and on one filesystem you application doesn't have delete privileges and on the other filesystem it does.  If you are auditing the filesystem, OS logs should show what process is deleting the file and when.

Comment: @DubStep - no, nothing in the app deletes the files, apart from this one remove op. The app just relies on the OS to eventually clean up everything else. The app runs as `www-data` on both systems, and both `/tmp` are `drwxrwxrwt`, as expected. No auditing enabled.

Comment: `/tmp` traditionally has been a shared space for all local services and users and also been a big source of security problems for all kinds of services. Symlink attacks and DoS vulnerabilities due to guessable /tmp temporary files are common. That's why systemd introduced the [`PrivateTmp=yes`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#PrivateTmp=) setting.  If `true` that sets up a new file system namespace for the executed processes and mounts private `/tmp/` and `/var/tmp/` directories inside it that are not shared by processes outside of the namespace.

Comment: Afaik `PrivateTmp=yes` is the default for Apache2 in the recent Ubuntu versions, which may explain some of your problems.

Comment: @HBruijn - interesting - I think you must be right, but both machines have `PrivateTmp` true. So I presume that one Apache managed to run both `program1` and `program2` in the same process, and the other has them in different processes, so maybe the `remove` is irrelevant. Both apaches have `mod_cgid`. I think the answer must be to set `PrivateTmp` off. But why is it on anyway? This isn't a system service - why would `systemd` care if I want to have two Apache processes talking to each other?

Comment: It might be interesting to see what happens when you don't use `/tmp` to store your files and/or (temporarily) disable the `PrivateTmp=true` setting by changing the apache2.service systemd unit file (see https://serverfault.com/a/840999/37681)